# Unable to push service to PCF, error staging application in buildpack compile phase

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a service to PCF using `cf push` command. I am getting the following error:

```
-----> Java Buildpack v4.16.1 (offline) | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#41b8ff8
   [Buildpack]                      ERROR Finalize failed with exception #<RuntimeError: No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifacts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation. >
   No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifacts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation.
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 1

Exit status 223
   Cell 73976a3c-ee0d-4c45-8067-55f73fc1b90a stopping instance 13e76fc9-87be-40be-a3b7-0f0cb1efc55f
   Cell 73976a3c-ee0d-4c45-8067-55f73fc1b90a destroying container for instance 13e76fc9-87be-40be-a3b7-0f0cb1efc55f
   Cell 73976a3c-ee0d-4c45-8067-55f73fc1b90a successfully destroyed container for instance 13e76fc9-87be-40be-a3b7-0f0cb1efc55f
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

I have the following contents in my yml file:

```
applications:
- name: Someapplication
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  memory: 1G
  path: target/someapp-SNAPSHOT.jar
  instances: 1
  env:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: env1
```

Comment: Based on the tags you're trying to push a Spring Boot app? Has it been built; what *is* at `target/someapp-SNAPSHOT.jar`? Are the detection criteria met per https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-spring_boot.md?

Comment: @jon, thanks for editing and corecting the title. Yes its a Spring boot app and the build is successful and i see a .jar file created under target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar was not generating properly. I added this plugin and was able to resolve the issue.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774751/spring-cloud-foundry-issue-223 ?

Comment: GOLDEN! Thank you